# How to self host ASP.NET Core Web App in Windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can self host my ASP.NET Core application successfully instead of hosting in IIS.

But now i am facing one problem.

Below is my .NET core project, it is a console application project.

[image]

**Program.cs :**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppCoreWeb
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseUrls("http://localhost:5001")
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .Build();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


namespace ConsoleAppCoreWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;            
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices()
        {
            // Includes support for Razor Pages and controllers.
            //services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.Run(context => context.Response.WriteAsync("hello world"));
        }
    }
}
```

All worked fine and screenshots of result as below:

[image]

[image]

After i modified the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class as below, the problem appeared.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Includes support for Razor Pages and controllers.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

**Error Message when invoke `BuildWebHost` method in `Program` class :**

```
"The ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type IServiceCollection."
```

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Clean and rebuild. What you have there should work.

Comment: Share us the content of **.csproj**, fail to reproduce your issue, try the content like `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>CoreMVC2_0.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change signature from:

`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

to

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```